# Git blame on a renamed file that is not yet committed

Tags: git

I have a file which I renamed using `git mv oldfilename newfilename`

How do I do a git blame on this file before I have committed this change? The rename is not picked up as it hasn't yet been committed.

```
> git blame newfilename
> fatal: no such path 'newfilename' in HEAD
```

And the old file name no longer exists.

```
> git blame oldfilename
> fatal: cannot stat path 'oldfilename': No such file or directory
```

Comment: I'm curious why you want to do this. Why not a blame before the rename? Or a blame after the commit (which you can always undo).

Comment: @NoufalIbrahim I've had this problem many times myself.  Things like blame and log are commands you run while working for investigative purposes, not as planned steps in the process.

Comment: @NoufallIbrahim working on a visualisation tool as a plugin for vim which requires me to blame the open file (if it is checked into version control.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given that you told git about the file move, you'd think it could figure it out.  But it doesn't.

The `--contents` switch will accomplish what you want.  From the `git-blame` man page...

```
--contents <file>
   When <rev> is not specified, the command annotates the changes starting
   backwards from the working tree copy. This flag makes the command pretend as if
   the working tree copy has the contents of the named file (specify - to make the
   command read from the standard input).
```

`git blame --contents newfilename -- oldfilename` will do a blame log on oldfilename as it appeared at HEAD, but use the contents of newfilename as the latest revision.

For the general problem of doing a blame on a file which, for whatever reason, no longer exists, pass in a specific revision for `git blame`.  `git blame <rev> -- <file>`.  So `git blame HEAD -- oldfilename` will give the blame log for oldfilename as of the last commit.

`--` is normally used to tell a command to stop processing options and treat what follows as a normal argument.  However, `git blame` appears to be overloading that normal meaning to mean "don't look for a file"... I think.  It's not entirely clear from the docs.

See ["SPECIFYING RANGES" in the "git-blame" man page](http://csurs.csr.uky.edu/cgi-bin/man/man2html?1+git-blame#lbAG) for details.